# Select entire row based on a logic applied on 2 columns across multiple rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Below is the input Dataframe(In real this is a very large Dataframe)

[image]

**Get the latest income of an employee which has  Income_age ts <10 months and if there is no Income data within less than 10 months take the value from sourcedIncome column for that account instead of taking from Income column**
the above logic goes to calculateIncome function below

Expected output Dataframe

[image]

Below is what I'm planning to implement

```
case class employee (EmployeeID: Int, INCOME: Int, INCOMEAGE: Int, JOINDATE: Int, DEPT: String)

val empSchema = new StructType().add("EmployeeID","Int").add("INCOME", "Int").add("INCOMEAGE","Date") . add("JOINDATE","Date"). add("DEPT","String")

//Reading from the File
import sparkSession.implicits._

val readEmpFile = sparkSession.read
  .option("sep", ",")
  .schema(empSchema)
  .csv(INPUT_DIRECTORY)

//Create employee DataFrame
val custDf = readEmpFile.as[employee]

//Adding Salary Column
val groupByDf = custDf.groupByKey(a => a. EmployeeID)
val k = groupByDf.mapGroups((key,value) => performETL(value))

def performETL(empData: Iterator[employee]) : new employee  = {
  val empList = empData.toList
  //calculate income which has Logic to figure out latest income for an account which is < 10 months and returns the latest income
  val income = calculateIncome(empList)

  for (i <- empList) {    
      val row = i
      return new employee(row.EmployeeID, row.INCOMEAGE , income)
  }
  return  "Done"
}
```

Is this the right approach to implement? 
If not, please suggest a better way to implement the same.

The solution has to be feasible for both batch and structured streaming .

Comment: how do you calculate 10 months?

Comment: That should be part of calculateincome function

Comment: you should post that code too then for better answers

Comment: The code mentioned above is suffice for one reason i.e. The above code should suffice to suggest if using mapgroups which takes function which In turn takes row iteration as argument is a better approach or not ? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: If we can see your code then we can suggest if there's a built in function to do the things you are doing. well by seeing your code I can't run to a conclusion though.